# python : How to make a combination according to the count of elements?

Tags: python, list

```
import random
import itertools

method_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
random.shuffle(method_list)

per = list(itertools.permutations(method_list, 4))

for ele in per:
    ss = set(list(ele))
    if len(ss) == 4:
        if not ('h' in ss and 'i' in ss):
            result.append(ss)
```

I want to make a total of 250 random combinations by taking 4 elements from my list.

like this:

```
{'c', 'b', 'd', 'a'}, {'c', 'e', 'b', 'a'}, {'c', 'b', 'f', 'a'}, {'c', 'b', 'g', 'a'}...
```

| no | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 160 |
| 2 | b | 160 |
| 3 | c | 160 |
| 4 | d | 160 |
| 5 | e | 160 |
| 6 | f | 50 |
| 7 | g | 50 |
| 8 | h | 50 |
| 9 | i | 50 |
|  |  | 1000 |

But I don't know how to make a combination that matches the number of elements according to the criteria in the table above.

The criteria are as follows.

1. No duplicate alphabets in a combination.
2. **h** and **i** are not in the same combination.
3. total of **250** combinations while meeting the number of elements.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Check out random.sample

Comment: Do you need an exact match of the restrictions in the table, or is some variation acceptable?

Comment: I need a result that exactly matches the conditions shown in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers don't try to meet the *requirements in the table* (only the exclusion of a joint occurrence of `h` and `i`), which I see as the main challenge of the question. My answer also doesn't do that *exactly*, only *approximately*:

```
from random import choices

pop_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
pop_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i']
weights = [80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 25, 25, 50]

combos_1 = [choices(pop_1, weights=weights, k=4) for _ in range(125)]
combos_2 = [choices(pop_2, weights=weights, k=4) for _ in range(125)]
combos = combos_1 + combos_2
```

The [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) function chooses randomly (without replacement) from a population, and accepts a `weights` sequence (which serves as kind of a preference for the choosing). So, as I said, this doesn't solve your problem exactly, only approximately (the larger the sample size, the smaller the relative error). The result looks like:

```
part        a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    sum
--------  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  -----
combos_1   74   85   71   92   88   20   21   49    0    500
combos_2   71   90   81   74   78   24   28    0   54    500
combos    145  175  152  166  166   44   49   49   54   1000
```

If you want to make sure that there are only *unique* combinations, then this would be better:

```
combos = set()
while len(combos) < 250:
    combos.add(tuple(choices(pop_1, weights=weights, k=4)))
    combos.add(tuple(choices(pop_2, weights=weights, k=4)))
if len(combos) == 251:
    combos.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import random
result = list()
for _ in range(250):
    x = random.sample(method_list,4)
    if x.count('h')>0 and x.count('i')>0:
        pass
    else:
        result.append(x)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `random` library could be avoided if using `set` properly, since returns always an unordered collection of terms. The counting part can be delegate to `Counter` from the `collections` library.

```
import collections as cl
import itertools as it

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
exclude = set('hi')

combinations = []
combinations = list(set(c for c in it.permutations(l, 4) if not exclude <= set(c)))[:250]

counter = cl.Counter(l)
counter.update(it.chain(*combinations))

counter_ordered_by_key = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda c: c[0])
print(counter_ordered_by_key)
# [('a', 120), ('b', 128), ('c', 114), ('d', 110), ('e', 121), ('f', 131), ('g', 121), ('h', 79), ('i', 85)]
```